# Export .scss to build folder?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, sass

## Problem

I'm re-using [React components](https://github.com/vega/voyager/tree/master/src/components) of the [Voyager project](https://github.com/vega/voyager). After building Voyager (`yarn build`), I can import components to my own project like this:

```
import { DataPane } from 'datavoyager/build/components/data-pane/index';
```

But I have one problem: the `index.js` file will contain lines like this:

```
var styles = require("./data-pane.scss");
```

Yet that `data-pane.scss` file was not exported to the `/build` folder during `yarn build`.

I know that `data-pane.scss` is in `/src/components/data-pane/`. **But how do I copy the `.scss` files of each component from `/src/components/` to `/build/components`?**

## My Attempts

- I've been looking at their [build script](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/scripts/build.js). Should I use `fs.copySync()` to copy each `.scss`?
- I also looked at [webpack.config.prod.js](https://github.com/vega/voyager/blob/master/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L125). The scss-related config looks like this:

[image]

- I have seen many questions on SO about how to export `.scss` as `.css` during build. I simply want to copy & paste the original `.scss` to the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding a function to Voyager `scripts/build.js`

```
// Copy scss files from /src/components/ to /build/components/ for external app to use Voyager components
function copyScss() {
  fs.copySync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/components'), {
    dereference: true,
    filter: (path) => {
      if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return path.endsWith('.scss');
      }
    }
  });
}
```